# Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, connection refused

Tags: centos, iptables, mongodb

So I am currently trying to setup mongodb running and hosting locally for my centos machine.
But when I try to connect I get this:

```
#mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.24
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2021-04-20T22:06:51.585+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2021-04-20T22:06:51.585+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:240:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I've read a lot about it now.

- User mongod is ownerr of /var/lib/monogodb
- File /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock doesn't exist
- Restarting the server caused this issue.

I think (personally) think it's something to do with iptables somehow.
When I start mongodb service I get this:

```
# service mongod status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status mongod.service
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-04-20 22:05:26 UTC; 27s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 1772 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=51)
  Process: 1770 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1768 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1766 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 20 22:05:25 Server-Elf systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Apr 20 22:05:25 Server-Elf mongod[1772]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Apr 20 22:05:25 Server-Elf mongod[1772]: forked process: 1774
Apr 20 22:05:26 Server-Elf mongod[1772]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 51
Apr 20 22:05:26 Server-Elf systemd[1]: mongod.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=51
Apr 20 22:05:26 Server-Elf systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 20 22:05:26 Server-Elf systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
```

Iptables setup:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

/etc/mongod.conf shows this: net: bindIp: 127.0.0.1

The error continues even after stopping iptables tho.. I'm so lost
Help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Your log shows errors during service startup, meaning you can't connect to a non-running process. Look into this line ```ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 51``` and try to find something about error 51 for mongodb

Comment: I found one "solution"
Editing the /etc/mongo.conf with "nojournal = true" then it shows error 2 instead of 51.

Comment: If you care about the data you should keep the journal activated. Is this a new setup? Do you need the data from the mongo database?

Comment: What is the full story? What are the recent changes, or events?

Comment: Changes in iptables for obvious reasons. And after a reboot the connection was denied. Even stopping iptables from running didn't get it back on track tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annoying, but only work around:
Restore old backup of entire server.

While this is obviously not ideal, I could not find a way to re-open access to 127.0.0.1:27017

Some data lost, but oh well, I had backup of most of it - just setting it up again now.

Thanks for the help/advice yall.

Comment: The problem was not the connection, bu the fact that service was failing to start. It was either a permission issue or a DB corruption.